# Android / Java, Observer update parameter standardisation : how to override an Enum

Tags: java, android, enums, observable, overriding

The question is a little complicated so I'll do my best to explain it clearly.

I want, for my android app, a standard system that updates the UI whenever a Bean is updated. I saw that `Observable` class is made for it. I notify the observers whenever I change something in the beans.

Though, as I can have an important number of observers for the same object instance in my app, I don't want all of them to redraw UI if only one observer needs to be triggered, for a particular property change. I saw that we could add an Object parameter in `notifyObserver` method.

Therefore, I wanted to standardize that parameter. I created a class `StandardObserverParameter<T>`. This class needs to hold the property of T that's been changed (so the observers `update` methods can `return` immediately if they are not concerned by the change of the given prop). I created, for each of my bean class, a PropertiesObservables enum that contain an identifier related to each of the bean prop I consider observable.

So, each of my beans has that enum `PropertiesObservables`.

The problem comes with the type of the `propertyChanged` prop of my `StandardObserverParameter<T>` class.

When I create the class `StandardObserverParameter<T>` :

```
class StandardObserverParameter<T> {
  T.PropertiesObservables mPropChanged ; 

  StandardObserverParameter(T.PropertiesObservables propChanged)
  {
    mPropChanged = propChanged ; 
  }
}
```

The problem is that Java doesn't know that PropertiesObservables enum is common to all my beans.

What I tried so far is that :

```
class ObserverStandardArgument<T extends ObservableStandard>
{
    T.ObservableProperties propChanged ;
    ArrayList<Object> additionnalArgs ;
}

abstract class ObservableStandard extends Observable {
    enum ObservableProperties { }
}


public class Member extends ObservableStandard
{
  private String mName ; 
  // ...

  @Override enum ObservableProps { name, ObservableProp2, .. }

  void setName(String name) {
    mName = name ; 
    setChanged(); 
    notifyObservers(new ObserverStandardArgument(Member.ObservableProps.name, ..));  
  }
}
```

But, looks like Java doesn't allow to override enum declared in parent class. I know I could use String identifiers, but it would be less precise for the observers `update` methods..

My question is : what's the workaround to let the developers of observers `update` methods choose the property they want in the autocomplete menu of the IDE ? (avoiding them to type raw String prop identifiers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use PropertiesObservables mPropChanged instead of T.PropertiesObservables mPropChanged. This will work